# VS 2017: Reference required to assembly

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-2017, assemblies

It seems, that in VS 2017, a project using an overloaded method, needs to have references to all the types of all the overloaded methods, even if it uses just one of these overloaded methods.

For example, consider ClassLibrary1 with the classes ServicedComponent1 and SharedMethods:

```
Public Class ServicedComponent1
    Inherits EnterpriseServices.ServicedComponent
End Class

Public Class SharedMethods
    Public Shared Sub DoDispose(ByRef obj As Messaging.Message)
        obj.Dispose()
    End Sub
    Public Shared Sub DoDispose(ByRef obj As EnterpriseServices.ServicedComponent)
        obj.Dispose()
    End Sub
End Class
```

In ConsoleApp1, which references ClassLibrary1 and System.EnterpriseServices, I have the following Module:

```
Module Module1
    Sub Main()
        Dim obj1 = New ClassLibrary1.ServicedComponent1
        ClassLibrary1.SharedMethods.DoDispose(obj1)
    End Sub
End Module
```

When I try to compile ClassLibrary1, I get the following error:

```
1>C:\temp\TestReferences\ConsoleApp1\Module1.vb(5,9): error BC30652: Reference required to assembly 'System.Messaging, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' containing the type 'Message'. Add one to your project.
```

In VS 2010, ConsoleApp1 compiles successfully, because I do not use the first overloaded method that uses System.Messaging.Message. I only use System.EnterpriseServices.ServicedComponent for which I have a reference in ConsoleApp1. It seems, that VS 2010 is smarter than VS 2017, because it finds out that the reference to System.Messaging is not needed.

1. Why does VS 2017 require a reference to System.Messaging?
2. Is there an option, so that VS 2017 behaves in this respect as VS 2010?

Comment: I'd guess that VS 2017 requires the reference because it needs to have enough knowledge about all of the overloads in order to select the correct one---it won't know that there is an exact match until after it's already assembled the details of the set of candidates and evaluated them in turn.  I could imagine a carefully-designed case going the other direction where something like the VS 2010 behavior could give different results when the type involved in the other overload is known vs. unknown.

Comment: Is it possible to turn that feature off in VS 2017?